# How to add/import a Django project into a virtualenv?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I just starting to use `virtualenv` and I want to import an old Django project into a new `virtualenv`. What is the best way to do this?

I tried to just copy my old Django project inside the new `virtualenv`, but Django is compiling with the old Path project and not with the one inside of the `virtualenv`.

Comment: How do you know? I mean, if you run `python manage.py runserver` inside your `(virtualenv)` environment, it should use its own `python` interpreter. How are you executing the app after copying it inside the `virtualenv`?

Comment: Like that, using python manage.py runserver. But when I start the app on the browser I got an error, and is pointing to the template of my old project, even running the manage.py inside of my environment.

Comment: Oh! Here is an idea, maybe is because my PATHS in my settings.py are pointing to the old project. Let me check!

Comment: Yes, normally you don't want to _hardwire_ your paths. Do something like this inside your `settings.py`: `import os
settings_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(settings_dir))
` and then concat `PROJECT_ROOT` with everything you want to declare as path.

Comment: You are right! Thank you! Do you want to write an answer?

Comment: Ok I'll do just in case someone have the same issue. I'm glad you could make it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work immediately. Just copy/paste the Django app folder into the `virtualenv` environment and when you issue `python manage.py runserver` on that folder, it should use `virtualenv`'s own `python` binary with it's `site-packages` path.

Checkout your paths inside your Django app. Don't *hardwire* them, you should do something like this:

```
import os
settings_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(settings_dir))
```

and then concatenate `PROJECT_ROOT` with everything you want to declare as path inside your `settings.py`

Hope this helps!